# Form flickers when changing image on 1 tick delay

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a title screen for a C# Game i'm making. I created a video to use as the background for the title screen, and extracted the frames to JPEG files. Using this:

```
    int frame = 1;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (frame == 901) { frame = 1; }
            this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("src\\titlescreen\\0 (" + frame + ").jpg");
            frame++;
    }
```

The form flickers when changing the image. The timer is on a 1 tick delay.

Is there any way to stop this?

Additional info: The form is maximised.

Thanks in advance,

DMP9

Comment: did you use double buffering ? That might solve it.

Comment: 1 tick??? 100-nanoseconds? that cannot be correct

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Is there any article on how to do so?

**EDIT:** This worked! Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to be sure first so please mark my answer.

Comment: Not related to the question, but the idiomatic way of cycling through the images would be to number them from 0 to N-1 and to get the next frame number by using the modulo operator: `frame = (frame + 1) % N;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to enable double buffering.
It is just a simple attribute you should be fine with it.